# Pointer assignment truncates the pointer from 64bit to 32bit

Tags: c, void-pointers

I have been trying to modify a piece of code in `likewise-open` and am totally stumped here.

Some background

Working on this [file](https://github.com/vmware/likewise-open/blob/dev/lsass/server/auth-providers/ad-open-provider/adldap.c), trying to code around some LDAP queries:

```
typedef void *MYH;
typedef MYH HANDLE;

HANDLE hDirectory = NULL;     
hDirectory = LsaDmpGetLdapHandle(pConn);
```

The LsaDmpGetLdapHandle() is defined [here](https://github.com/vmware/likewise-open/blob/dev/lsass/server/auth-providers/ad-open-provider/lsadm.c)

```
typedef void *MYH;
typedef MYH HANDLE;

HANDLE
LsaDmpGetLdapHandle(
    IN PLSA_DM_LDAP_CONNECTION pConn
    )
  {
    return pConn->hLdapConnection;
  }
```

where PLSA_DM_LDAP_CONNECTION is `typedef` for following `struct`:

```
struct _LSA_DM_LDAP_CONNECTION
  {
  ...
    // NULL if not connected
    HANDLE hLdapConnection;
  ...
  };
```

Basically, there is `HANDLE` type everywhere.

**Note**: Just to avoid various `*.h` files defining it differently, I added that `typedef void *MYH;` in both files

**The trouble**:

The code would crash after the line where `hDirectory` is assigned from what is returned by `LsaDmpGetLdapHandle` and I try to further use `hDirectory`

**What I have debugged, till now**:

Attaching gdb, `hLdapConnection` in `pConn` is:

```
(gdb) p pConn->hLdapConnection
$5 = (void *) 0x7feb939d6390
```

However, `hDirectory` is:

```
(gdb) p hDirectory
$6 = (void *) 0xffffffff939d6390
```

**I fail to understand why the difference, after assignment ??**

Also, to note, the `939d6390` in both the pointer addresses is common.

Interestingly, both of these approaches work

```
// If I pass hDirectory reference
LsaDmLdapGetHandle(pConn, &hDirectory);

// where this function is defined as, in the other file:
DWORD
LsaDmLdapGetHandle(
    IN PLSA_DM_LDAP_CONNECTION pConn,
    OUT HANDLE* phDirectory)
{
  HANDLE hDirectory = NULL;
  hDirectory = LsaDmpGetLdapHandle(pConn);
  *phDirectory = hDirectory;
  return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

// Or I call another function, which then call LsaDmpGetLdapHandle(), in the other file
hDirectory = LsaDmLdapGetHandleCopy(pConn);
HANDLE
LsaDmLdapGetHandleCopy(
    IN PLSA_DM_LDAP_CONNECTION pConn)
{
  HANDLE hDirectory = NULL;
  hDirectory = LsaDmpGetLdapHandle(pConn);
  return hDirectory;
}
```

I thought, maybe something to do with HANDLE definitions being different in those 2 files, hence I added my own `void *` definitions in both files

Comment: There is not enough (or too much) information in this question. It does not contain the faulty code (like in  [mcve]). It is referring to some non-standard and undocumented  library, which can be buggy by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144151/64-bit-function-returns-32-bit-pointer)

> By default all return values are int. So if a prototype is missing for function then compiler treats the return value as 32-bit and generates code for 32-bit return value. Thats when your upper 4 bytes gets truncated.

Comment: Yes, that was it !! The first file was missing the `.h` which was included in second file. Hence calling it in second file worked fine, however directly calling it in first one truncated the pointer after assignment